# Running a JAR I compiled: "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"

Tags: java, jar

I just recently recovered some programs from my old hard drive, so I tried compiling one and running it, and I get this error in command prompt:

Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I compiled the program with Java 8, and I ran it with Java 8. The only thing I can think of is the fact that I used Java 7 with the program on my old computer. Also, I'm using Windows XP on this new computer, while I used Windows 7 on the old computer.

I am using two libraries, but I don't think that is the issue since the program ran fine in NetBeans.

Any ideas of what the problem is?

Comment: Double check your environment variables. It's possible your IDE is pointing to Java 8, but your system is running Java 7 or earlier.

Comment: I did check that, and I checked again. Java home and path are pointing to Java 8.

Comment: If you're getting that through your command line, then try `java -version` command

Comment: make sure you look a the list of Related question on the side, this is a popular on stack

Comment: I have. You should read "I compiled the program with Java 8, and I ran it with Java 8.".

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to archetype's answer, my guess is that java 7 is in one of your windows directories, like C:\Windows\System32 and that directory is before your JAVA_HOME directory in your path. Try typing 'where java' on the CMD. If it's in more than one directory, see which one comes first in your PATH variable and look at the version of java in that directory.

Comment: CMD said the command "where java" (without quotes) was not recognized. Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: No, maybe 'where' is not included in all versions of DOS. Look in your C:\Windows\System32 directory and see if you have java.exe in there. If you do, then type 'C:\Windows\System32\java -version' and see what it is. If it's version 7, type 'echo %PATH%' and see if C:\Windows\System32 comes before whatever your JAVA_HOME\bin directory is in the list of paths. If it does, either remove java.exe from C:\Windows\System32 or change your PATH variable to list the JAVA_HOME\bin directory before C:\Windows\System32. Also, make sure JAVA_HOME\bin is in your path.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that, the code was compiled in later version but your default runtime is running on the lower version. you can do this by simply checking your current version. `java -version` and `javac -version`. You may need to check the Java from the `Control Panel`. To verify the actual version of your `JAR` file, you may need to extract the actual version and look for the version information

`javap -verbose <Java_Class_Name> | findstr "major"`

Comment: Well this is odd. I did java -version in CMD, and it's giving me 7. However, I have all the environment variables set to Java 8, so I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: @user1845954 - I think you need to read up on how Windows environment variables really work; e.g. how their values propagate from where they are set to where they are (can be) used.

Comment: Yeah I get the basic concept of them but you're probably right... The environment variables are probably the issue, because XP cannot load the Java 8 installer, so I had to extract the installer contents and add the environment variables manually. Which is where I could've went wrong. For now, I just downloaded the Java 7 JDK. Thanks for the advice.